# I'm trying to save the state of qtreeview with the directories expanded or not (load in the state I left when I closed .) using Qsettings but I can't

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview, qsettings

I am using the code below. Mainwindow's state is preserved but qtreeviw's is not.
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore

```
class MyApp(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.tree = QTreeView()
    self.settings = QSettings('testorg', 'testapp')
    
    try:
        self.tree.header().restoreState(self.settings.value("estado_header"))
        self.resize(self.settings.value('window size'))
        self.move(self.settings.value('window position'))
    except:
        pass
   
    self.model = QFileSystemModel()
    self.model.setRootPath(r"C:\Users\dan-s>")
    self.tree.setModel(self.model)
    #self.tree.header().restoreState(self.settings.value("estado_header"))
    #self.tree.collapseAll()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.tree)
    self.setLayout(layout)


def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.settings.setValue('window size', self.size())
    self.settings.setValue('window position', self.pos())
    state = self.tree.header().saveState()
    self.settings.setValue('estado_header', state)
    super().closeEvent(event)
 
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)        

demo = MyApp()
demo.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tried other ways but I can't solve it.

Comment: You're trying to restore the state *before* setting the model, at that point the header has no sections. Move that restore *after* calling `setModel()`. Also, you should use [`saveGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry) and [`restoreGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry).

Comment: The header doesn't store the state of directory expansion, so restoring it won't be much use. You'll have to roll your own solution, which will need to allow for the deletion/renaming of directories between visits.

Comment: I tried the first suggestions above but it didn't work

Comment: @DaniloSilva Actually, I was wrong and misread your question (sorry about that): the fact is that you're not saving or restoring anything: `saveState()` and `restoreState()` are functions of the *header* (the section visibility, order, size and sort indicator), which is completely unrelated to the expanded/collapsed state of the view. In order to do that, you need to do what described above by ekhumoro: save the paths that are expanded and *try* to restore them when restarting the program.

Comment: musicamante thanks for your help. I'm trying to do what ekhumoro indicated. If it works i'll put it here.